# How odometry data generated from IMU and motor encoders

Tags: ros, odometry, imu, sensor-fusion, encoders

I am working on an autonomous robot that needs `nav_msgs/Odometry` to work with ros navigation stack

`nav_msgs/Odometry`

```
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
string child_frame_id
geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance pose
  geometry_msgs/Pose pose
    geometry_msgs/Point position
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
    geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
      float64 w
  float64[36] covariance
geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance twist
  geometry_msgs/Twist twist
    geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
    geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
  float64[36] covariance
```

and I have motor 2 motor encoders that publish `ticks` as the motor rotates and an IMU which pubish data as `sensor_msgs/Imu`

```
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
  float64 w
float64[9] orientation_covariance
geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular_velocity
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
float64[9] angular_velocity_covariance
geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear_acceleration
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
float64[9] linear_acceleration_covariance
```

how `odometry` data generated from these sensors or if I add more localization sensors like `GPS` and `Magnetometer` than these two sensors how I can fuse them to get `Odom` data that are compatiable with ros navigation stack

Answer (score 0):

That data may be fused in the robot localization module.

http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/robot_localization/html/index.html